# Android WallpaperManager.setBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) sometimes sets the default wallpaper

Tags: android, wallpaper

I am using WallpaperManager.setBitmap to set the device's wallpaper.
I have the permissions set correctly. It works fine for 99% of the times however sometimes it simply sets the default instead of mine.
There is no exception (I have try-catch and I have logs. No exception. No crashes. Nothing).
The method is void so there is also nothing to check after calling it.
It is just being called and instead of setting the given bitmap - it sets the default.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html#setBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)

Here's the code:

```
WallpaperManager.getInstance(context).setBitmap(bitmap);
```

**The bitmap is not recycled** (I am checking for it before reaching this line of code).

Any ideas what can go wrong or what alternative to use?

Using a **resource is not an option** as the bitmap is dynamically generated in memory.

The generated bitmap size, in my device's case (Nexus 5) is always the same: 2160x1920, regardless the successful or failure results.
Also - it is a PNG.

I will meanwhile run some tests with setStream instead:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html#setStream(java.io.InputStream)

Hopefully it works better ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this method instead, to directly reference the bitmap as a drawable resource:

```
WallpaperManager.getInstance(context).setResource(R.drawable.myImageId);
```

The method call assumes your bitmap is in a drawable resource folder (and not e.g. assets).

See [API docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html#setResource(int)) for more details.

Comment: The bitmap is generated in memory. Using a resource is not an option. I updated the original question to mention this.